# Совместимость шифрования между С++(CryptoPP) и Python(что-нибудь) AES-256 CBC

Tags: c++, криптография, python-3.6, aes

Вот часть что с с++

```
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MIN_KEYLENGTH] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G' },
iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'};

std::string plaintext = "test";
std::string ciphertext;
std::string decryptedtext;

AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES::MIN_KEYLENGTH);
CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new StringSink(ciphertext));
stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(plaintext.c_str()), plaintext.length());
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

QByteArray bytes = ciphertext.data();
qDebug() << bytes.toHex();
qDebug() << bytes.toBase64();
```

Вывод

HEX = "E70CF56C1FFC2476429F767C9C8DAA8A"

Base64 = "5wz1bB/8JHZCn3Z8nI2qig=="

А тут Python(3.6) PyCrypto

```
data_bytes = "test                ".encode("ascii")
key_bytes = '123456789ABCDEFG'.encode("ascii")
iv_bytes = "1234567898765432".encode("ascii")

def encrypt(message, passphrase):
aes = AES.new(passphrase, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
return base64.b64encode(iv_bytes+aes.encrypt(message))
```

Вывод

Base64 = 'MTIzNDU2Nzg5ODc2NTQzMp/W7BB2eheEoiJdi+AF1JU='

Есть высокая вероятность, что я упускаю здесь что-то принципиально важное, как бы я мог это поправить???

Comment: Ну как минимум iv в C++ вы задали числами, а в Python ASCII-символами - и в итоге получаются очевидно различающиеся значения iv.

Comment: @andreymal да я заметил это, я поправил, но результат по прежнему расходится

Comment: Поправьте в тексте вопроса, а то непонятно, как вы там поправили

Comment: Ну и да, в C++ вы кодируете текст `test`, а в Python почему-то `test                ` — это очевидно разные тексты, которые в зашифрованном виде просто обязаны выглядеть по-разному

Comment: Кроме того, в коде C++ с использованием StreamTransformationFilter вы неявно использовали PKCS1 паддинг (в Crypto++ 5.0 и новее он используется по умолчанию), а в коде Python вы никакого паддинга не использовали

Comment: @andreymal да, сча поправлю, и в Python я как бы вручную добил до 16 байт, а то в противном случае на просто test эта реализация ругается.

Comment: «эта реализация ругается» потому что вы не применили паддинг и вообще очень слабо понимаете что делаете и как работает криптография

Comment: @andreymal есть такое, подробнее про паддинг и как его использовать, что касается base64 в с++ то он такой 5wz1bB/8JHZCn3Z8nI2qig== и он сходится с тем, что я получил на стороннем web-ресурсе.

Comment: А ещё, похоже, вы используете библиотеку PyCrypto, которая протухла шесть лет назад. Почему бы не взять что-нибудь поновее вроде [cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/)?

Comment: @andreymal в питоне я профан немного, поэтому взял первое что попало от гугла под руку. Спасибо за наводку попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES (Rijndael-128) шифрует данные только блоками по 16 байт (128 бит). Чтобы шифровать текст произвольной длины, его делят на блоки и последний блок дополняют каким-нибудь паддингом до нужной для AES длины. Некоторые режимы (например, CTR) умеют обходиться без паддинга, но для используемого у вас CBC паддинг нужен.

В вашем C++ коде в `StreamTransformationFilter` по умолчанию применяется паддинг [PKCS#7](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)#PKCS7). В Python-коде вы про паддинг напрочь забыли и вместо паддинга дополнили данные до размера блока тупо пробелами, что разумеется неверно.

Так как библиотека PyCrypto [протухла](https://theartofmachinery.com/2017/02/02/dont_use_pycrypto.html) и не содержит встроенного паддинга, придётся изобретать его самостоятельно (впрочем, я позаимствовал код из невыпущенной версии PyCrypto).

И да, приписывать `iv_bytes` в `b64encode` не надо, если вы его в C++ коде тоже не приписывали.

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def pad_pkcs7(data_to_pad: bytes, block_size: int) -> bytes:
    # https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Util/Padding.py
    padding_len = block_size - len(data_to_pad) % block_size
    padding = bytes([padding_len]) * padding_len
    return data_to_pad + padding


def unpad_pkcs7(padded_data: bytes, block_size: int) -> bytes:
    pdata_len = len(padded_data)
    if pdata_len % block_size:
        raise ValueError("Input data is not padded")

    padding_len = padded_data[-1]
    if padding_len < 1 or padding_len > min(block_size, pdata_len):
        raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
    if padded_data[-padding_len:] != bytes([padding_len]) * padding_len:
        raise ValueError("PKCS#7 padding is incorrect.")

    return padded_data[:-padding_len]


data_bytes = b"test"
key_bytes = b"123456789ABCDEFG"
block_size = 16  # всегда 128 бит для AES
iv_bytes = b"1234567898765432"  # длина должна быть block_size байт

# Зашифровка
aes = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
ciphertext = aes.encrypt(pad_pkcs7(data_bytes, block_size))
print(base64.b64encode(ciphertext))

# Расшифровка
aes = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
decryptedtext = unpad_pkcs7(aes.decrypt(ciphertext), block_size)
print(decryptedtext)
```